# Attempting to make a bank's deposit/withdraw function to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="checking" class="account">
    <h2>Checking</h2>
    <div id= "checkingBalance" class="balance">$0</div>
    <input id="checkingInput" class="input" type="text" placeholder="enter an amount" />
    <input id="checkingDeposit" class="deposit" type="button" value="Deposit" />
    <input id="checkingWithdraw" class="withdraw" type="button" value="Withdraw" />
</div>

<div id="savings" class="account">
    <h2>Savings</h2>
    <div id="savingsBalance" class="balance">$0</div>
    <input id="savingsInput" class="input" type="text" placeholder="enter an amount" />
    <input id="savingsDeposit" class="deposit" type="button" value="Deposit" />
    <input id="savingsWithdraw" class="withdraw" type="button" value="Withdraw" />
</div>

<script 

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#checkingBalance").on("click", function() {
            var checkingBalance = 
            parseInt($("#checkingBalance").html()).replace("$","")
            console.log("This is the checking balance. " + typeof checkingBalance)

            var deposit = parseInt($("checkingAmount")).val()
            console.log("This is the deposit: "+ deposit)

            var total = deposit + checkingBalance
            console.log("This is the total: " + total)

            $("#checkingBalance").html("$" + total)

            if (total > 0) {
                $("body").removeClass("zero")
            }
        })
    });
```

Right at the bottom is my attempt in retrieving the value and changing from the deposit box and the withdraw box. The JS at the bottom is my attempt, but it seems like it is not the solution I was looking for.

Comment: `<script` should be `<script>` for a start

Answer (score 0):

No element at `html` has `id` `#checkingAmount`, `javascript` is also missing `#` before `checkingAmount`.

Substitute `#checkingInput` for `checkingAmount`. Set `value` attribute of `#checkingInput` element to `"0"` at `html` to avoid `NaN`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="checking" class="account">
      <h2>Checking</h2>
      <div id="checkingBalance" class="balance">$0</div>
      <input id="checkingInput" class="input" type="text" value="0" placeholder="enter an amount" />
      <input id="checkingDeposit" class="deposit" type="button" value="Deposit" />
      <input id="checkingWithdraw" class="withdraw" type="button" value="Withdraw" />
    </div>
    <div id="savings" class="account">
      <h2>Savings</h2>
      <div id="savingsBalance" class="balance">$0</div>
      <input id="savingsInput" class="input" type="text" placeholder="enter an amount" value="0" />
      <input id="savingsDeposit" class="deposit" type="button" value="Deposit" />
      <input id="savingsWithdraw" class="withdraw" type="button" value="Withdraw" />
    </div>
    <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#checkingBalance").on("click", function() {
        var checkingBalance = parseInt($(this).text().replace("$", "")); 
        console.log("This is the checking balance. ", checkingBalance); 
        var deposit = parseInt($("#checkingInput").val()); 
        console.log("This is the deposit: " + deposit);
        var total = deposit + checkingBalance; 
        console.log("This is the total: " + total); 
        $("#checkingBalance").html("$" + total);
        if (total > 0) {
          $("body").removeClass("zero")
        }
      })
    });
  </script>
  </body>

</html>
```